# if statement in python not working with or and integers

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I'm having a problem with an `if` statement which has an `or` in it as well. I am essentially trying to have it so that if either of the player's score is 50, the game ends. 
I'm trying to have my code saying something like this:

```
if ball.score2 or ball.score1 == 50: 
    EndGame()
```

However, when I have this, as soon as the thing which ups `ball.score2` (but this only happens for whichever one is first in the `if` statement, so here it does not do it if `ball.score1` is upped) happens, and it is meant to be upped by 5, it runs the `EndGame()`. They work individually, so if I have:

```
if ball.score2 == 50:
     EndGame()
```

It will end the game when `ball.score2` gets to 50, but not when I use them both like in the first example. Could someone help?

Comment: Yeah your right that one solves the problem - sorry, didn't see it when i looked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the equality of each scores:

```
if ball.score2 == 50 or ball.score == 50:
    EndGame()
```

Comment: it might also be good to recommend adding parenthesis for additional clarity.

Comment: I always wondered if it's possible to do something about it so I wouldn't need to check everything separately and without writing a function with *args for example ?

Comment: @Granitas: `if 50 in [ball.score2, ball.score]`. See the marked duplicate question for more info.

Comment: oh it's so obvious... how about if we would replace or with and?

Comment: For and: `if len(set([ball.score2, ball.score1, 50])) <= 1` ... but it's not as clear or intuitive.